# KQL - Ignoring items with property not equal to value

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013

I have to configure the site search so that it does not include items wich have a property of ModerationStatus != 1. I found out that using a query like `ModerationStatus <> 1` can probably solve my problem, but I am not sure if it will work in my environment since not all possible search items have this property of ModerationStatus. Can someone show me an example query that might work in such case? I am kinda new to KQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured it out. I'd have to white two queries combined like this:

(ContentTypeId: 'ContentType that has ModerationStatus' ModerationStatus <> 1) OR (ContentTypeId <> 'ContentType that has ModerationStatus')

I apologize for the dumb question.